# What's the word for "to make someone dislike something"?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a single word (verb) that means to make someone dislike something or make them not do what they are doing. The following example might better explain what I am looking for.

Example: I was going to play an online game. My friend was sitting with me while I was playing that game. He criticized that game so much and narrated so many disadvantages of the game that he made me dislike or kind of discouraged me from playing it (even though it could be a good game). So I would like to say:

"My friend criticized that game so much that he -----**WORD**ed----- me the game."

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with 'discourage'?

Comment: My friend criticized that game so much that he [**put me off**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+off) it."

Comment: He **soured me on** the game.

Comment: At the absolute margins, one could use words like ***soured, disenchanted, jaundiced*** as a relatively unusual *transitive* construction (with "me" as the object). But it would be far better not to insist on that particular aspect of the context.  As @WeatherVane says, actual native speakers would avoid it in favour of *he **put / turned me off** the game*

Comment: At [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) a lot of questions appear to be [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I don't think there is an equivalent here – someone asking if they can say **this**, when such a question is difficult to answer, and does not really solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully sure if I can answer my own question but I have found the word I was looking for and I am posting it as an answer in case anyone find it helpful.

**Deter** is what I was looking for, I asked a few native speakers the same question and they told me that my friend deterred me from playing the game.

**[Deter](https://www.lexico.com/definition/deter)** means "Discourage (someone) from doing something by instilling doubt or fear of the consequences."

My sentence could be written as "My friend deterred me from the game"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that two possibilities are "soured" and "disenchanted".

Examples:

"My friend criticized that game so much that he soured me to it."

"My friend criticized that game so much that he disenchanted me with it."

Comment: The correct phrasal verb is [**sour on**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sour%20on), not **sour to**.